# Multiple Monitor - multiple browser windows at the same time

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a monitor connected to my net book **Samsung N145** however my problem is displaying two different screens to enable me to use two different websites at the same time.

If  anybody could help that would be great, the monitor is A HP 1530 if this helps.

Comment: That's a strange title for a question.

Comment: Who is Mr Fletcher, and why is he your subject?  Oh, and what version of Windows are you running, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Use extend mode instead of clone mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the "Easy Display Manager" installed then pressing Fn + F4 will let you choose or cycle between the different modes with an external display, the one you want is DualView. As shown in the manual (which annoyingly uses Flash). Alternately you can open the display settings window in the control panel, select monitor 2 and check the "Expand to fit this monitor".

[image]